# Typo in tooltip on community wiki post signature

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/in-python-how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary/12420427#12420427) today on SO which was a part of community wiki.

When I hover over the "community wiki" phrase, it shows the following tooltip:

> This post is community owned as of 5 mins ago. Votes do not generate reputation, and it can be edited by users with 100) rep.

There is a typo mistake after the numeral 100: A closing bracket is there of no use.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This typo is fixed now. Thanks.